# Can't run make - gcc: command not found

Tags: nvidia, compiling, make, cuda

I'm trying to [follow a tutorial to get CudaMiner](https://litecointalk.org/index.php?topic=3231.0) working on Linux. I have PAINSTAKINGLY installed NVidia drivers, Cuda 5.0 and incidentally I'm failing on the last step when I run `make`:

```
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/var/progs/CudaMiner'
Making all in compat
make[2]: Entering directory `/var/progs/CudaMiner/compat'
Making all in jansson
make[3]: Entering directory `/var/progs/CudaMiner/compat/jansson'
gcc -std=gnu99 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../..     -g -O2 -MT dump.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/dump.Tpo -c -o dump.o dump.c
/bin/bash: gcc: command not found
make[3]: *** [dump.o] Error 127
make[3]: Leaving directory `/var/progs/CudaMiner/compat/jansson'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/var/progs/CudaMiner/compat'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/var/progs/CudaMiner'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I'm pretty sure I have gcc, in fact I have multiple versions of it. I installed version 4.6 (which is what cuda requires) but it doesn't seem to find it. I'm so close!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get install build-essential`?

Comment: build-essential is already the newest version

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do this: open a terminal and type `gcc --version`. Does anything come up?

Alternatively, search for the gcc executable, which should be located in /usr/bin.
Do `ls /usr/bin | grep gcc`. What output do you get from that command?

If you get no output from either command, then you need to find your gcc executable wherever you installed it (somewhere in /usr/share maybe?). When found, do `cd /usr/bin && ln -s [ABSOLUTE PATH OF GCC]`.

If you got no output from the first, but output from the second, then you have serious trouble, because /usr/bin is not in your PATH. Edit the file `/etc/environment` and ADD the following line to the end of the document: `PATH="$PATH:/usr/bin"`.

If you got output from the first, then there is a problem somewhere with bash not reading its own PATH. I think hell would freeze before the first works, but watch you prove me wrong and freeze hell for me. :)

Hope this helps! +1 me if it does!

Comment: To check if gcc is in the path, it's better to run 'which gcc'.

Comment: My case 1st command doesn't found gcc, 2nd command found gcc. So I tried your solution to add the `PATH="$PATH:/usr/bin` to environment file, but unfortunately doesn't work.

Comment: @Jason this question is about 5 years old now. I'd suggest opening your own question with as much info that you can give. Where did the second command show your gcc is located?

Comment: @Zzzach... I found out that I didn't create a symbol link between gcc --> gcc-[the version I want], which is why the gcc-[certain version] is already in the file system but couldn't be called in shell. Your solution should work actually.

Answer (score 33):

Maybe simple...

```
sudo apt-get install gcc
```

... could be enough?

Comment: That's `gcc`'s one fatal flaw. It only works correctly if installed.

Answer (score 3):

/usr/bin/gcc is a link to the gcc compiler in use

It is not unusual to have multiple versions of gcc installed. there binaries are in the same folder, e.g. gcc-4.4  gcc-4,6 and gcc-4.7

The link /usr/bin/gcc will point to one of these versions. If it is the wrong version, then the change the link to gcc-4.6.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to use gcc and tools that are needed by it, try installing build-essential:

```
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Comment: sudo apt update , then sudo apt install build-essential